# My Brilliant Friend title explanation

Tags: plot-explanation, title, my-brilliant-friend

[*My Brilliant Friend*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Brilliant_Friend_(TV_series)) (Italian: *L'amica geniale*),
TV series, based on Ferrante's second Neapolitan Novel and titled *My Brilliant Friend: The Story of a New Name* (Italian: *L'amica geniale – Storia del nuovo cognome*)

But it isn't clear who is the titular “Brilliant Friend?” Is there something lost in the translation? Is it just a catchy title?

I can guess it means either Elena, or how Elena and Lila view each other, but it isn't clear

Comment: ["Lila insists that Elena, being Lila's brilliant friend, should never stop studying."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neapolitan_Novels#My_Brilliant_Friend_(2011))

Comment: @BCdotWEB it seems the Elena finds Lila as brilliant also, no? and Elena doesn't feel so brilliant, no?

Comment: I do not know, I have not watched the series nor read the books. I wouldn't be surprised however, if one of them explicitly refers to the other. Or perhaps it does refer to both.

Comment: @BCdotWEB - "perhaps it does refer to both". having read the books and about to watch the third series, I would say that this is my take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that "Brilliant" is how they both view each other, and that who is the "brilliant friend" shifts back and forth throughout their friendship. There's a certain edge of envy in their friendship. In the beginning, Lila is seen to be a prodigy, and Elena at one point says:

> "  When   Lila stopped   misbehaving   and   effortlessly   outdid   me,   the teacher  praised  me  first,  with  moderation,  and  then  went on  to  exalt  her  prowess.  I  felt  the  poison  of  defeat  more acutely  when  it  was  Sarratore  or  Peluso  who  did  better than me ... Certainly I trained myself to accept readily Lila’s superiority in everything, and even her oppressions”(p32).

Then, Elena is able to continue on her education and Lila is not - Lila is jealous that Elena can continue down the path that she thought would be her way out of the neighborhood. While Elena moves into (and struggles in) the world of academia, Lila works in a factory and remains entrenched in the poverty of their childhood. Elena continues to find success as a writer and becomes known as 'brilliant' in her own right, but is still heavily affected by criticism she receives by Lila, who Elena continues to view as being the 'brilliant' one.

The dynamic between them is heavily influenced by these cycles of jealousy. I think that the phrase 'my brilliant friend' holds both bitterness and idolization of the other, summarizing their consistent rivalry throughout their lives. It implies a sense of resentment over the other's achievements, while also defining them by their relationship to the speaker.